# How to discard check out document by REST API in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

To check out file in REST API there is method

```
var strURL = GetWebAbsoluteUrl() + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + currentItemURL + "')/CheckOut()";
```

But what will be method to discard check out? Please help.

Comment: how about using `/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + currentItemURL + "')/undocheckout()";` ?

Comment: Awesome, have posted it as answer. Please accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `UndoCheckOut` method to discard a check out of a document.

Make an `HTTP POST` request to the below mentioned endpoint:

`/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + currentItemURL + "')/undocheckout()"`

Reference - [UndoCheckout method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileUndoCheckOut)